# Linux Service Application permission to create files

Tags: linux, unix

I have application written in go, that locate in to ~/work/bin directory and(should, but it don't) creates files in to ./images/
It runs as service with following configuration:

```
Description=My Application Description
After=network.target

[Service]



User=AdminName
Group=www-data
ExecStart=/home/AdminName/work/bin/Application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What should i modify to add permission on create files? Should i create and add group or modify folder attributes? Or change destignation folder to somthing public with right permission?

Warning Code on attempt to create file:

> ● Application.service    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/systemd/system/Application.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-12-10 15:02:09
>   MSK; 50min ago  Main PID: 28262 (Application)    CGroup:
>   /system.slice/Application.service
>              └─28262 /home/AdminName/work/bin/Application
>
> Dec 10 15:02:09 **** systemd[1]: Started Application.service. Dec 10
>   15:02:09 **** Application[28262]: Started... Dec 10 15:02:28 ****
>   systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/Application.service:1] Assignment
>   outside of section. Ignoring. Dec 10 15:02:28 **** systemd[1]:
>   [/etc/systemd/system/Application.service:2] Assignment outside of
>   section. Ignoring.

Comment: First fix the warnings with `[Unit]`. The warning is completely not related to creating files....

Comment: Use `WorkingDirectory=/path/to/directory/where/images/directory/lives`. Also, it's not a good idea to run a service from a user's home directory, nor is it a good idea to write data to a relative path.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd.

Answer (score 0):

> Use WorkingDirectory=/path/to/directory/where/images/directory/lives.
>   Also, it's not a good idea to run a service from a user's home
>   directory, nor is it a good idea to write data to a relative path. –
>   Jonathon Reinhart 2 hours ago

Solved